# SQL Server CE Insert into table doesnt seem to increment identity

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-ce-4

I have a table defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ItemCategory
(
    ID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CategoryID INT NOT NULL,
    ItemID INT NOT NULL
);
```

This table links to two tables on the two foreign keys.

I have this SQL statement

```
INSERT INTO ItemCategory (CategoryID, ItemID) 
VALUES (@category, @item)
```

with the parameters being set as follows:

```
var p1 = new SqlCeParameter("@category", SqlDbType.Int);
var p2 = new SqlCeParameter("@item", SqlDbType.Int);
p1.Value = categoryID;
p2.Value = itemID;
```

The values of the parameters are correct (I have debugged and checked) therefore there shouldn't be any foreign key errors.

When I execute the SQL statement I get the following error:

> The column cannot contain null values. [ Column name = ID,Table name = ItemCategory ]

However I don't understand this as the `ID` column is set as an `Identity` column and therefore I should not have to supply a value and it should be auto incremented automagically.

Why could this be?

- C#
- SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0
- Visual Studio 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `IDENTITY (1,1)`

```
 [Id] int NOT NULL  IDENTITY (1,1)
```

Comment: It seemed to work by explicitly adding the seed and increment so thanks.